# Run javascript in MVC Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc, controller

Im not sure if my title is correct, because I am not quite sure where to start with my problem. But let me explain what I want to do:

I want to create a Controller method in my MVC C# .NET project that returns a value. Usually, I would just write "return Content(value)", however this particular value is generated through JavaScript code. To make it a little worse, the value is also generated through one of the Google APIs that uses ajax requests.

I have managed to return a PartialView, but when I run a get-request on this, the response is just the script I have running on the page, obviously.

To summarize, I need to return just this particular value (a string), and to get this string, I must wait for the ajax in the script to finish. Whats the technique I should do for this??

Comment: Is the controller an ApiController? I slightly confused, usually we use api controller so the font end code can get something out or write some into the server. Not sure why you need to controller if the front  end has this value already. If the backend wants it, you probably should move your google api call into the backend?

Comment: Well, I made the controller so that I can make a request to my own url with an ID. In the controller, I use Entity Framework to get data from a database with the ID I entered. The data contains a start-position and end-position, and I use the javascript (Google API) to calculate the distance. One idea I got just now is to make a new request in the script to a new url with the distance and insert from there. But is this the preffered way??

Comment: ok, I see. So what you have are the start and the end positions. what you want to return is the distance between the two positions. In this case you probably should call google api from within your controller. I don't know much about google api but if it is  just a restful web service then you can call it easily from the backend.

Comment: An alternative approach is to return the start point and the end point from your controller  (eventually they are what you have) and let the consumer of your controller to deal with the google api call.

Comment: This could of course work, but there is a limitation of requests to Google. I have decided to add a new column in my database with the distance, so that it is only calculated the first time (or if its edited) and not every time the data is retrieved.

Comment: Sure, then you can check in your controller if the database record has a distance then just return it otherwise go for google and then save the distance into your db.